# Recursion Error when calling more than one function

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, recursion

I have 2 separate functions that print comparison counts for array sorting alghoritms (insertion sort and quick sort). In these functions I call the sorting alghoritm 4 times with 4 different lists.

```
Alg. / Comparison count:        l=10    l=100   l=1000  l=10000
Insertion-sort:                 18      198     1998    19998

Alg. / Comparison count:        l=10    l=100   l=1000  l=10000
Quick-sort:                     41      797     13392   214916
```

The problem is taht I can only call one of these functions and if I call both I get recursion error on the quick sort function

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

So this

```
make_arrays()
print("Alg. / Comparison count:\tl=10\tl=100\tl=1000\tl=10000")
print_comp_insert()
```

and this

```
make_arrays()
print("Alg. / Comparison count:\tl=10\tl=100\tl=1000\tl=10000")
print_comp_quick()
```

work fine but this

```
make_arrays()
print("Alg. / Comparison count:\tl=10\tl=100\tl=1000\tl=10000")
print_comp_insert()
print_comp_quick()
```

causes an error.

I don't really understand what's happening here.

Comment: How do you initialize the arrays? Are quicksort and insertion sort running on two distinct copies of the shuffled array? If you sort the array with insertion sort, then it becomes sorted. If you then call quicksort on the same array, you're attempting to sort an array which is already sorted. Which should work fine, although quicksort performs notoriously worse on sorted arrays than on shuffled arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an upper limit to the number of recursive calls you can make.  You can expand the limit with this:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(<put integer here>)
```